# Linq2Sql Equivalent of DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

in my linq 2 sql i had a SP with multple resultsets and a code

```
[Function(Name = "GetHomedashboard")]
[ResultType(typeof(TopSearch))]
[ResultType(typeof(TopVacancy))]
public IMultipleResults Usp_CandidateStats_MultipleRs([ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] int? profileId)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), profileId);
    return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

that retrieves those sets

is there an equivalent method in EF that i can use to do achieve the same functionality.
basiclay i'm looking for an equivalent of **ExecuteMethodCall** Method in EF

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeFirst in Entity Framework, I found this [NuGet Package (CodeFirstStoredProcs 2.5)](http://nuget.org/packages/CodeFirstStoredProcs/) is useful to execute stored procedures. I don't know if there is an API call in Entity Framework you can call directly to execute.

Comment: can i retrieve multiple resultsets with this?

Comment: yes, take a look at here :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures